# Azure SendGrid DeliverAsync works but not Deliver

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I wired up SendGrid using their documentation as a guide. Nothing fancy here, just want to fire off an email for certain events. Looking at the code below, the SendGrid documentation directs me to use transportWeb.**Deliver**(message) but this results in "cannot resolve symbol Deliver" However if I use DeliverAsync everything works fine. Just seems sloppy to define a variable that is never used.

```
SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
message.AddTo(to);
message.From = new MailAddress(from);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Text = body;
var uid = AppConfigSettings.SendGridUid;
var pw = AppConfigSettings.SendGridPw;
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(uid, pw);
var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
// transportWeb.Deliver(message); // "Deliver" won't resolve
var result = transportWeb.DeliverAsync(message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Deliver()` [was removed](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600---2015-4-22) in the most recent version of the library. Can you link me to the docs that are out of date?

Comment: Here's the link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email/

Comment: Here's the section heading: "The following examples show how to send a message using the Web API."